# Tracking Google Analytics events with Angulartics

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, mixpanel, event-tracking

I am using Angulartics to do the tracking on my website. https://github.com/luisfarzati/angulartics

Events are tracked on mixpanel as well as google analytics. Mixpanel events are tracked as desired. However, Google analytics does receive the page views but does not track any events at all. I know that GA requires a "category" as well as a "action" to be set for each event.

So my event tracking basically looks like this,

```
<a ng-click="bookingModal($parent.$index)"  href="{{trip.bookings[0].providers[0].url}}" target="_blank">Test </a>
```

Basically, I have a simple ng-click on my event (some events can be fired without clicking).

in my controller I have the following:

```
$scope.bookingModal=function (trip){
        var clickedIndex=trip;
        var detailTracker={
          eventCategory: 'bookingModalClicked',
          eventAction: 'bookingModalClicked Action',
          userMail:Auth.user().email,
          userName:Auth.user().user,
          clickedIndex: clickedIndex
        };
$analytics.eventTrack('clickBooking',detailTracker);
```

This tracking works perfectly fine with mixpanel, but events are not tracked with GA. What am I doing wrong? I dont seem to find my mistake.

Comment: I am not sure where does `eventCategory` and `eventAction` comes from, but in documentation, it is just `event`, and may be also `action`

Comment: I stuck with the google documentation on that and they call it eventCategory all the time. But you're right-...thanks for your help